# Can't login to joomla 3.4.8 administrator

Tags: joomla3.4

I've this wired problem.All of sudden for some computers can't login to the joomla administrator and get redirected back to the login page without any error messages.
I've tested the website on a local server and the issue didn't reproduced.Only on the live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a white space issue.
There is an extra line in the joomla index file that causes this redirect problem once removed it everything works fine.